# Using exec() functions to Call Linux Command in C

Tags: c, linux, exec

I've been stuck trying to do this for a while now, and I just cannot get it to work no matter what I try.

My C code looks like this:

```
char *const parmList[] = {"ps","-o pid",processID,NULL};
execvp("/bin/ps", parmList);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `processID`?  If it is a string that contains the PID, you'll be fine.  If it is an integer, then you will have problems — it should be a string; all arguments to a command are strings.  And, FWIW, the command as written would work on Mac OS X, but fails on Linux with `error: improper format list` (but on Linux, you could use `ps -opid,ppid,time` with no space between the `-o` and the list of columns to be printed, or with two separate arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, I think you are executing

`ps "-o pid,ppid,time" 3817`

Try this:

```
char *const parmList[] = {"ps","-o","pid,ppid,time",processID,NULL};
execvp("/bin/ps", parmList);
```